# Toggle not working for DOM rendered HTML elements after reloading

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, toggle

I'm making a weather app and I want to click a button to convert between imperial and metric. I also have a search bar and when I enter a location, a dropdown menu would appear and I can click on one of the items and the HTML page would reload with new info.

Before clicking on any dropdown item (with initial values on the page), the toggle button works fine. But after I click on a dropdown item and the page reloads, the button works **only** for HTML elements that I wrote **directly** into the .html file. For the other elements that I wrote into HTML **through DOM**, it doesn't work.

Relevant code below.

```
async function init (name) {
  await fetchCurrentData(name)

  const forecastHoursList =  await hoursList(name)
  document.querySelector('.forecast ul').innerHTML = renderHourlyForecast(forecastHoursList)

  const forecastDailyList =  await dailyList(name)
  document.querySelector('.future ul').innerHTML = renderDailyForecast(forecastDailyList)
}


// initial value
await init('Miami')


// toggle function below
const button = document.querySelector('button')
const hidden = document.querySelectorAll('span.hidden')
const visible = document.querySelectorAll('span.toggle')

button.addEventListener('click', event => {
  hidden.forEach(el => {
    el.classList.toggle('hidden')
    el.classList.toggle('toggle')
  })
  visible.forEach(el => {
    el.classList.toggle('hidden')
    el.classList.toggle('toggle')
  })


//Render data into HTML elements
const renderHourlyForecast = (forecastHoursList) => {
  const renderedForecastList = forecastHoursList.map((el) => {
    return `
    <div>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li><h4>${el[0]}</h4></li>
          <li><img src="${el[1]}"></li>
          <li><span class="toggle" style="float: left">Temp °C</span><span class="hidden" style="float: left">Temp °F</span><h4 class="temp">${el[2]}</h4></li>
          <li><span class="toggle" style="float: left">Feels °C</span><span class="hidden" style="float: left">Feels °F</span><h4 class="temp">${el[3]}</h4></li>
          <li><span class="toggle" style="float: left">Wind kph</span><span class="hidden" style="float: left">Wind mph</span><h4 class="windspeed">${el[4]}</h4></li>
          <li><span style="float: left">Cloud cover</span><h4>${el[5]}%</h4></li>
          <li><span style="float: left">Precip chance</span><h4>${el[6]}%</h4></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </div>
    `
  }).join('')
  return renderedForecastList
}


//Searchbar input event below
const onInput = async event => {
  const cityList = await autoComplete(event.target.value)

  if(!cityList.length) {
    dropdown.classList.remove('is-active');
    return
  }

  resultsWrapper.innerHTML = ''
  dropdown.classList.add('is-active');

  for(let list of cityList) {
    const option = document.createElement('a')
    option.classList.add('dropdown-item')
    option.innerHTML = renderOption(list)

    //Dropdown click event below
    option.addEventListener('click', async () => {
      dropdown.classList.remove('is-active');
      search.value = list[0];
      await init(list[0])
    });

  resultsWrapper.appendChild(option)
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the <h4> tag is not part of the problem here. It's the <span> tag with toggle and hidden classes.

Comment: Any error on the browser's console?

Comment: nope nothing came out on the console.

Answer (score 0):

> The button works only for HTML elements that I wrote directly into the .html file. For the other elements that I wrote into HTML through DOM, it doesn't work.

This is happening because you used `innerHTML+=` as the `DOM` Subtree of the main element is completely reconstructed, the event handlers are destroyed. Better use the `event.target` to check whether the element clicked is a dropdown element or not.

For example

```js
const fruits = ['Pineapple', 'Coconut', 'Mango'],
  list = document.querySelector('ul');

fruits.forEach(fruit => {
  list.innerHTML += `<li>${fruit}</li>`
})

list.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'li')
    e.target.innerText = e.target.innerText.split('').reverse().join('');
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Apple</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but i'm not sure if I follow. 

1. I used innerHTML to reconstruct the subtree, so the event handler is destroyed => Not sure what you meant? Does it mean event handler will not work on anything that's reconstructed using DOM? (thus button clicking event not working? But my button works before clicking on dropdown. Or you mean if I click dropdown this event will not reconstruct my DOM?)

2. Use event.target to check whether it's a dropdown menu => but it will always be a dropdown item. How does that actually help?

Comment: 1. Whenever an element is dynamically inserted in a parent element, the whole parent element's subtree is reconstructed like `document.write`.  So all the associated event listeners are destroyed.

Comment: Your code seems incomplete. Please update the code

Comment: my code is several pages long, would a github link help?

Comment: sure. But try using `e.target` on `dropdown-item` and see whether its working or not.

Comment: hm I think my incomplete code above is misleading - it's not the dropdown-item that's the issue (and i tried it's not working)
This is the Github link: https://github.com/tommy-ling/Weather-App
After inputting a value in the search bar and clicking on the item, the button stopped working for the middle and bottom section which were written using DOM method